# Botão enviar de uma form

Tags: php, html

Tenho um contact form no meu site, só que tenho um problema! Quando faço enviar ele está a redireccionar para a home e eu não quero que faça isso quero que se mantenha no mesmo sitio e não estou a conseguir perceber o porque de ele fazer isso.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="row">
      <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

           <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
             <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" value="<?= $name ?>">
              <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $email ?>">
               <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="message" type="text" value="<?= $message ?>" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>

             <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <button class="btn pull-right" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Enviar</button>
             </div>

             <div class="success"><?= $success; ?></div>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` ele não está na home?

Comment: sim está! mas a pagina está dividida em 4 partes, e na 4º eu tenho os contactos onde contém a form e quando carrego enviar ela vai para o topo da pagina e eu não quero isso, quero que fique na secção dos contactos.

Comment: Leia sobre *fragment* da URL.

Comment: Ao enviar o form a página é recarregada, logo vai pro início.

Comment: e como posso fazer para a pagina não ser recarregada de novo? é mesmo quando faltam campos para preencher ela devia se manter no mesmo sitio, mas não ela vai igualmente para o topo da pagina e depois quando faço scroll até ao form tenho lá a mensagem de que faltam os campos para preencher.

Comment: Para a página não ser carregada vc terá que usar Ajax.... para o form não ser enviado com campos vazios, você pode usar `required` ou fazer uma validação via JavaScript.

Comment: Só que o `required` só funciona em HTML5, por isso acho mais válido fazer via JS

Comment: Mas eu já tenho essa avaliação em javaScript, por exemplo eu meto o nome, mas não meto o email e carrego para enviar, ele vai para o topo da pagina e depois quando faço scroll aparece lá mensagem de que falta o email. É ai que está o meu problema, eu quero que ele fique no mesmo sitio, porque senão dá a sensação que o email já foi enviado e não foi, porque ainda faltam campos para preencher.

Comment: Então a sua validação está errada, está permitindo o envio do form mesmo sem os campos estarem devidamente preenchidos.

Comment: @Chip A questão é sobre o posicionamento após o post ou validação do form?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo após os post, porque ele se eu não preencher os campos todos não envia o email, logo está a fazer bem a validação dos campos.

Comment: @Chip você testou a minha sugestão?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sim, eu até já tinha isso definido, tanto que se eu na barra de navegação eu clicar na área dos contactos ele acrescentas ao url /#sec_05 e se for assim eu carrego no enviar e ele fica na área dos contactos, mas se eu não carregar na barra de navegação e simplesmente fizer scroll quando entro no website até ao contactos ele não assume o #sec_05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma hash para a sua action e uma âncora em seu html, assim ao recarregar a página após o post, o scroll será feito para até o formulário novamente.

No seu caso como o destino da action é a mesma página, você poderia inclusive utilizar apenas o target `<form id="contact" action="#contact" method="post">`

```
<div class="col-md-8">       
   <div class="row">
      <a name="contact"></a>
      <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#contact" method="post">

           <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
             <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" value="<?= $name ?>">
              <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $email ?>">
               <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="message" type="text" value="<?= $message ?>" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>

             <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <button class="btn pull-right" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Enviar</button>
             </div>

             <div class="success"><?= $success; ?></div>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Peço desculpa @Leandro Angelo ainda não tinha visto esta sua sugestão. Sim esta forma funciona, agora sim já está como queria ;) Obrigado pela ajuda.